# VBA find a word and add a column

Tags: vba

I would like create a macro (VBA) that find a word and in another cell give a word.
Example:

```
|A | B                     | macro result|
|--|-----------------------|-------------|
|1 |my cat is on the table | ok          |
|2 |Hi                     |             |
|3 |this is my house       | ok          |
```

I have try this but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

```
  Sub Macro1()
    riga = 1
    
    While (Sheets("Foglio2").Cells(riga, 1) <> "")
      If (Sheets("Foglio2").Cells(riga, 2) Like "my") Then
         Sheets("Foglio2").Cells(riga, 3) = "ok"
      End If
      riga = riga + 1
    Wend
    
  End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I correctly understand what you try accomplishing... Do you search in column B:B strings containing "my" and if they exists to write "ok" in C:C? If so, replace `If (Sheets("Foglio2").Cells(riga, 2) Like "my") Then` with  `If Instr(Sheets("Foglio2").Cells(riga, 2), "my") > 0 Then`

Comment: Why not use a formula like `=IF(COUNTIF( A2:B2; "my")>0;"ok";"-")

Comment: @FaneDuru very well, it is work!

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What does it do? Does it work partway and stop early? Does it not run/make any noticeable changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()
    riga = 1
    
    While (Sheets("Foglio2").Cells(riga, 1) <> "") 
If Instr(Sheets("Foglio2").Cells(riga, 2), "my") > 0 Then
         Sheets("Foglio2").Cells(riga, 3) = "ok"
      End If
      riga = riga + 1
    Wend
    
  End Sub
```